# Inject a bean as static dependency

Tags: java, spring

Inyecting dependency bean as static, could lead to problems?

```
@Component
public class SomeBean {
    
    @Autowired
    private static DependencyBean dependency;
    ...
}
```

Comment: The component bean would be a singleton, so its instance variable should only be injected once.

Comment: This wouldn't work as injection on `static` members isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring, CDI (and likely others like Guice, etc) don't allow you to "inject" a bean into a `static` field as a rule. Why would this be?

While Spring certainly *could* support injecting contents into static fields, conflict would arise if two copies of the bean were managed since static fields are shard among all instances of the class. In your example, you have exactly one managed instance, and it would "work" in that very narrow scope, but projects aren't usually that simplistic, which is why it is not supported by Spring:

```
<!-- not a real spring definition, just an example -->
<bean id="example1" class="com.example.SomeBean">
    <property name="dependency" value="dependencyV1"/>
</bean>
<bean id="example2" class="com.example.SomeBean">
    <property name="dependency" value="alternateDependencyV2"/>
</bean>
```

There are other reasons around classloading, constructors, and the whole philosophy of DI/IOC, but that is the main reason.

And there are ways to defeat this protection (not recommended): https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-static-field

Comment: That's what I was thinking, it was working just because `SomeBean` is a singleton bean (by chance). Thanks @jonathan

Comment: You're welcome :) With IOC/DI, the need for static variables sorta just goes away. The DI container can assemble the object graph you need for you if you tell it what to do!